# sort list by first name and last name then display to user

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a contact managers program in a console application using a list to store and display the data. I need to view a report that displays a summary of contacts available and then have a menu to allow the user to interact with the program. I have a method to create a list with data and a contact object. I made a method to sort by first name and a method to sort by last name but I am unsure as to how to display the contacts sorted back to the user.

any guidance would be appreciated

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {         
        //Declare the list

        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

        //Main Driver
        char menuItem;
         Console.WriteLine("Contact List\n");
        menuItem = GetMenuItem();
        while (menuItem != 'Q')
        {

            ProcessMenuItem(menuItem, contactList);
            menuItem = GetMenuItem();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, goodbye");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    //Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
    static char GetMenuItem()
    {
        char menuItem;
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nPlease pick an item: "));
        while (menuItem != 'C'
            && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'Q' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D' && menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'F' && menuItem != 'P' && menuItem != 'T')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
            DisplayMenu();
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(IOConsole.GetChar("\nEnter option or M for menu:"));
        }
        return menuItem;
    }

    static void DisplayMenu()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("C-> Create Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("R-> Remove Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("U-> Update Contacts");
       Console.WriteLine("D -> Load data from file");
       Console.WriteLine("S-> Save data to file");
       Console.WriteLine("L-> View sorted by last name");
       Console.WriteLine("F-> View sorted by first name");
       Console.WriteLine("P-> View by partial name search");
       Console.WriteLine("T-> View by contact type");
       Console.WriteLine("Q-> Quit");
    }

    //Routes to the appropriate process routine based on the user menu choice
    static void ProcessMenuItem(Char menuItem, List<Contact> contactList)
    {
        switch (menuItem)
        {
            case 'C':
                createContact();
                break;
            case 'R':
                removeContact(contactList);
                break;
            case 'U':
                updateContact(contactList);
                break;
            case 'D':
                LoadToFile();
                break;
            case 'S':
                saveToFile();
                break;

            case 'L':
                sortByLastName(contactList);
                break;
            case 'F':
                sortByFirstName(contactList);
                   break;
            case 'P':
                   DisplayList(contactList);
                   break;
            case 'T':
                   sortByContactType();
                   break;
            case 'Q':

                   break;

        }                   
    }


//Sorts the list by last name
         public static void sortByLastName(List<Contact> contactList )
        {

          contactList.OrderBy(c => c.GetLastName);




        }
        //Sorts the list by first name
         public static void sortByFirstName(List<Contact> contactList)
        {
           contactList.OrderBy(c => c.GetFirstName);

        }
```

Comment: `OrderBy` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can loop through that with a `foreach` statement and call `Console.WriteLine` for each item.

Comment: You're not sorting the `contactList`. With `contactList.OrderBy(...)` you are creating an `IEnumerable<Contact>`, and then you don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try this method:

```
contactList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.GetLastName, y.GetLastName));
```